# How can I perform a subquery in Core Data for to-many relationship?

Tags: iphone, core-data, subquery

I did some research and cannot find the answer to a simple Core Data issue.

Here is the simplified object model:

```
Person -->> Events
Event --> Date
```

What I would like to do is query all Persons and sort them by the most recent event.

I took a look at some postings on SUBQUERY within a predicate.  However, I don't know how to query for the most recent.  I can't use "event.date" in the Sort Descriptor as it is not allowed since it is an NSSet.

Some code for reference...

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

// The following errors:    
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"event.date" ascending:NO selector:nil];
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are approaching the problem backwards. You should fetch the `Event` objects sorted on date and then ask each `Event` object for its related `Person` objects.

You can create a subquery predicate to look for `Event` objects but you can't sort on a relationship.

Comment: Thanks TechZen. This makes sense. My next step is to somehow limit the query to "unique" persons so I can display only the person matching the most recent event.

Comment: Also, I suppose I can complete the fetch than place unique persons in an array and reference that for the table. However, I thought it would be more efficient to limit the query to unique values as the # of events will eventually be very large.

Comment: Discovered Core Data Snippets with [fetchRequest setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];  It's not working however. I get three persons matching the three events. I tried "setPropertiesToFetch" to use "Person.nickname" which is unique but I still get three events fetched.

Comment: I just realized fetching for Events will not work. When a new person is created there are no events yet so it will not be fetched and listed in the table view. This may be more complicated than I though.

Comment: Just one more comment. I figured it out! I will simply add a new field to Person which is set to the lastest event date. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding a new date field, "lastEvent", to the Person object which is updated with the latest event date. This way I can simply sort by the "lastEvent" field.